# How to validate if the string variables has only enum values in DTO in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, controller

```
public enum Status {
   NEW,
   RETRY
}

class RequestDto {
    private Status status;
}
```

I can do like above, but i need is:

```
@Data
public enum Status {

    NEW ("new"),
    RETRY("retry");

    private final String status;

    Status(String status){
        this.status = status;
    }


}


class RequestDto {
    private String status;
}
```

How can i validate the above status variable in RequestDto has only **new**, **retry**

Comment: What is the reason for the field being a `String`, and not `Status`?

Comment: I think this https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums is answer to your question

Comment: @Chaosfire because, so that i can change the case in values.
There is other enum also, where the value is CREDIT_LOSS. But i need creditLoss as input. I can't add creditLoss in enum. This is not standard

Comment: @Nemanja thanks for reply. can't we do it simply with annotation instead of creating the annotation and all

Comment: @Vishnupriya as far as I know, no. Most standard annotations can't be applied to enum types. I don't see other option.